# Twitter data mining project

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, pandas, twitter

I've written this simple code, that is possible to find on [my github profile](https://github.com/Gillis86/twitter-data-mining/tree/fa4d45a8fcb8e7fbee4cb04db1b4b958206648fa) (it simply downloads some twitter data and store in an excel file).

It is one of my first experiments of using OOP in python: the code works (does its tasks as intended) but maybe an OOP implementation is not explicitly needed in this case.

Can I show this code as part of my coder portfolio as it is, or need some adjustment?

This is the code:

#### main.py

```
from twitterHandler import Twitter_User
import pandas as pd
import threading




if __name__=='__main__':
    usersIDS = {'UserName1':1234,'UserName2':1234,
                'UserName3':1234,'UserName4':1234}
    threads = {}
    excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Twitter User's Report.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

    def get_data(user_id): #get best last tweets and store them in a excel file
        user = Twitter_User.Twitter_User(user_id,2000)
        user.get_tweets()
        #print(user.get_tweets())
        best_tweets = user.most_liked_rt()
        #print(best_tweets)
        best_tweets.to_excel(excel_writer, '{}'.format(user.name),index=False)
        excel_writer.save()
        excel_writer.close()


    for user_name,user_id in usersIDS.items():
        try:
            t = threading.Thread(target=get_data,args=(user_id,))
            threads[user_name] = t
            print('Starting to get data for: {}'.format(user_name))
            t.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Something wrong happens: ',e)


    for name,t in threads.items():
        t.join()
        print('Process for {} Stopped'.format(name))
```

#### TwitterUser.py

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import twitterHandler.twitter_data
import collections


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitterHandler.twitter_data.consumer_key, twitterHandler.twitter_data.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(twitterHandler.twitter_data.access_token, twitterHandler.twitter_data.access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class Twitter_User():
    '''Get information about a specific Twitter User'''
    def __init__(self, id, count=200):
        self.id = id
        self.count = count
        self.data = None
        self.like_average = None
        self.rt_average = None
        try:
            self.user = api.get_user(self.id)
            self.name = self._user._json['name']
            self.screen_name = self._user._json['screen_name']
            self.location = self._user._json['location']
            self.description = self._user._json['description']
            self.url = self._user._json['url']
            self.followers = self._user._json['followers_count']
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.response.text)
            return
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            rate = api.rate_limit_status()
            print(rate)
            return 

    def get_tweets(self): #store last n tweets in a dataframe
        simple_list = []
        for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=self.id).items(self.count):
            array = [status._json["text"].strip(), status._json["favorite_count"],
                    status._json["created_at"], status._json["retweet_count"],
                    [h["text"] for h in status._json["entities"]["hashtags"]],status._json["lang"]]
            simple_list.append(array)
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(simple_list, columns=["Text", "Like", "Created at", "Retweet", "Hashtags","Lang"])
        self.data = self.data[~self.data["Text"].str.startswith('RT')]
        return self.data


    def most_liked_rt(self): #return a df of tweets where the number of like and rt is greater than respective averages
        self.like_average = self.data["Like"].mean()
        self.rt_average = self.data["Retweet"].mean()
        return self.data.loc[(self.data['Like'] > self.like_average) & (self.data['Retweet'] > self.rt_average)]

    def count_hashtags(self,df): #give the most used hashtags in the tweets df - to use with the return df of most_liked_rt()
        h_tags_cloud = []
        h_tags = df[['Hashtags', 'Created at']]
        h_tags = h_tags[h_tags["Hashtags"].map(len) != 0]
        h_tags_list = h_tags["Hashtags"].tolist()
        h_tags_counter = collections.Counter()
        for h_inner_list in  h_tags_list:
            for h_element in h_inner_list:
                h_tags_cloud.append(h_element)
        h_tags_counter.update(h_tags_cloud)
        h_tags_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(h_tags_counter,orient="index").sort_values(0,ascending=False)
        h_tags_df = h_tags_df.rename(columns={0: 'HashTags Freq'})
        return h_tags_df
```

TwitterData.py

```
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have spend a few moments with your project and I have a few things which should be improved (in my opinion ofc).

1. **Use pep8 as your code formatting tool.** If somebody will be reviewing your code this will be the first thing which she/he notice. There is a lot of empty lines, wrong formating etc.
2. **Improve your README.md**. Add more info to your project descriptin. `Get some data from a Twitter user` is not enough :) Add some description for your API, maybe try to add some badges for codecov etc.
3. **Hardcoded value** - this is *bad smell*. Example:

> usersIDS = {'UserName1':1234,'UserName2':1234,
>       'UserName3':1234,'UserName4':1234}

4. **Use logger** - using print is good, but if you want to look more professional use logger ;) Also add more descriptive message
5. **Too broad exceptions** I know - sometimes this is impossible, but it looks like in few places it can be improved. For example line 31 in main.py. This looks weird for me, and would check what exactly can be broken here.
6. **Remove code which is comment** - please care what you show other people
7. **Add unit tests** - This is very very important. Add some unit tests. The best thing would be use TDD to create your app (Knowing what is TDD is very important on job interview)
8. **Add more descriptive comments**
9. **Naming of variables** - I know - this is very very hard, but your should not use naming like h_tags.

Also:
What is this:

> h_tags = h_tags[h_tags["Hashtags"].map(len) != 0]

It looks like a bug. Even if this do what should do, then it looks very weird and in my opinion should be refactored for something more readable.

Also your constructor looks weird. Catching exceptions in constructor is kind of *bad smell*.